# CSS - How to wrap <h1> and <h2> tags around a floated div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, word-wrap

I'm currently customising a WordPress theme and need to place the sidebar element in the main content area, so that the page text will wrap around the sidebar rather than having the content and sidebars in separate columns in the layout. The layout needs to work in this way because the page text will be at least three screens high whereas the sidebar will be approximately a quarter of a screen high, and a large amount of screen space will be wasted if I have the sidebar in its own column, because it's relatively wide (35% width of overall layout) even though it isn't that high.

Each page contains a main title marked up with the h1 tag immediately followed by a subtitle with the h2 tag. If I rely on the default "display: block" property for the h1 and h2 tags then the titles will be pushed underneath the sidebar (because a width of 100% is assumed?) but if I use the "display: inline" property then the main title and subtitle will appear on the same line rather than the subtitle appearing underneath the main title as expected. The text is then formatted into paragraphs after the h2 tag and these display underneath the subtitle as expected.

HTML code outputted by WordPress is as follows; CSS is limited to just the "display: inline" at the moment:

```
<div class="entry-content">

<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">

    <aside id="text-2" class="widget widget_text">

        <div class="textwidget">
            Sidebar content goes here.
        </div>

    </aside>

</div><!-- #secondary -->

<h1 class="entry-title">Solutions</h1>

<h2>Products</h2>

<p>Main content goes here.</p>

<h2>Services</h2>

<p>Main content goes here.</p>

</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

I would like to find a solution that doesn't require the h1 and h2 tags to be separated into their own floating divs because I don't want to make it difficult for the site owner to edit the pages afterwards or have a problem when they need to create new pages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: You should wrap the main content in a div then. eg `<div class="main"><!-- products --></div><div class="sidebar"></div>` anyways should give us a picture of what you want.

Comment: you just need to use `floats` - make a JSFiddle please

Comment: Thanks for responding. The issue with placing the content in separate divs is that the main content will not flow around the sidebar if I do this. I have not posted the CSS because it is very minimal - the sidebar floats in the top-right of the main content area correctly and the issue is to do with the h1 and h2 tags being inline with each other when they need to be displayed separately, so I need some way for them to still appear inline but for the setting to be "cleared" after the h1 tag.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this all you need?

```
.widget-area{
  float:left;
  ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/u7dRq/

Comment: Thanks for responding. I already have the widget area correctly floated (in the top-right of the content area) but the problem is that I cannot assign the correct style properties to the h1 and h2 tags so that they do not appear inline with each other. To get the correct effect I would need to add a line break after the h1 tag.

Comment: I don't see why you need display:inline on your headings. Just float the widget block left or right. The float:right variant: http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/u7dRq/1/

Comment: Willem - you are correct. The problem was that because the h1 and h2 tags had "clear: both" set (and I did not realise this) the only way I could make them appear to the side of the floated div was to set "display: inline", otherwise they automatically appeared underneath the sidebar.

Comment: Great! That's why people insisted on seeing all of your CSS or a JSFiddle :)